# Sorting broken when moving to Postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, sqlite

I'm deploying my application to heroku (and like a n00b) during my development I was using SQLite3. I deployed to Heroku and i'm getting errors for specific pages. I loaded up Postgresql as my development database and I noticed my errors are happening because of the sort function. This works perfectly fine in SQLite3 but is broken with Postgresql. Anyone have any idea on how to change the syntax to work with Postgresql?

```
def index
  @users = User.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 100).search(params[:search]).find(:all, :order => sort_order('id'))
 end

private
#called to sort the table. taking in case insensitive  
def sort_order(default)
  "LOWER( #{(params[:c] || default.to_s).gsub(/[\s;'\"]/,'')} ) #{params[:d] == 'down' ? 'DESC' : 'ASC'}"
end
```

here is the error i'm receiving

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in UsersController#index

PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR: function lower(integer) does not exist LINE 1: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY LOWER( id ) DESC L... ^ HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. : SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY LOWER( id ) DESC LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can cast the value to text, but you would need to check for postgres or break SQLite.

```
#called to sort the table. taking in case insensitive  
def sort_order(default)
  sort_col = (params[:c] || default.to_s).gsub(/[\s;'\"]/,'')
  sort_col += "::text" if ActiveRecord::Base.connection.class.to_s.match(/PostgreSQLAdapter$/)
  "LOWER( #{sort_col} ) #{params[:d] == 'down' ? 'DESC' : 'ASC'}"
end
```

Comment: What happens when `sort_col` is `id` and you have `1..10` as `id` values? The ordering will come out as `[1, 10, 2, ..., 9]` rather than `[1, 2, ..., 10]`.

Comment: this is working great. I'm not too concerned with the 1,10,2, issue because i have a search function built in as well. This function also allows me to sort without taking in the Model name if i want to expand this out to multiple Model types. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Rails knows the column types already and you can access this information through [`columns_hash`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaCache.html#method-i-columns_hash). The `columns_hash` maps the column name to a column object and the column objects have a `type` which matches the type you used in your `create_table`. For example:

```
User.columns_hash['id'].type
```

would give you `:integer` whereas

```
User.columns_hash['created_at'].type
```

would give you `:datetime`. That lets you do things like this in your `sort_order`:

```
def sort_order(default)
  c    = params[:c] || default.to_s
  type = User.columns_hash[c].type
  c    = "lower(#{c})" if(type == :string || type == :text)
  "#{c} #{params[:d] == 'down' ? 'DESC' : 'ASC'}"
end
```

You should, of course, be whitelisting `params[:c]` just in case someone tries to slip something nasty into your SQL but you can use `User.columns_hash.has_key?` for that:

```
cols = User.columns_hash
c    = (cols.has_key?(params[:c]) ? params[:c] : default).to_s
type = User.columns_hash[c].type
c    = "lower(#{c})" if(type == :string || type == :text)
"#{c} #{params[:d] == 'down' ? 'DESC' : 'ASC'}"
```

This sort of thing should even be portable across databases.

Answer (score 0):

"ID" is an INTEGER type? If so, simply remove the `LOWER()` function. If not, you will need to cast to TEXT or VARCHAR. Eg. `ORDER BY CAST(id AS TEXT)`

Comment: But sometimes the `params[:c]` column is used so it isn't always `id`. Also, integers sort differently than strings-which-contain-integers so I don't think casting is a good solution.

Comment: My mistake, I didn't pick up the part where it was not always the "id" column being sorted on.